# Can a Wordpress plugin (Blogroll) work on a non-Wordpress webpage?

Tags: wordpress

Specifically, we would like to have a Blogroll plugin on the Wordpress page, but have that also appear on a website. So when we update info in the Blogroll, that automatically appears on the website too.  Both the website and Wordpress are on the same server.  Would there be a specific Blogroll plugin that would do this, or is it generally possible with plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress plugins have a very specific structure, and are likely not very usable elsewhere, however as they're on the same server you can easily query the database with a mySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_links` WHERE `link_visible` = 'Y'
```

Assuming you're using PHP you could then echo it out like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_links` WHERE `link_visible` = 'Y'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo '<ul>';
while($link = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<li><a href="' . $link['link_url'] . '">' . $link['link_name'] . '</a>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: You can even do this if you're not on the same server so long as the mysql user has permission to do so from another server.